# Physical Width vs Content Width?

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS and I am having trouble with the concept of the physical width and content width. Sites seem to refer to them, without ever truly explaining the difference.

I know it has to do with teh CSS box model, if anyone else could help me out that would be great.

For example if given the following in css:

```
div {
width: 400px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin: 0px 10px;
border: 2px solid pink;
}
```

What is encompassed into the physical width? And what in the content width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- "Width" refers to the content area; think of it as the 'inside' of your box.
- "Padding" is *extra*, added on outside of the content area. It can be 0.
- "Border" is extra, outside of the padding, if any.
- "Margin" is extra again, outside of the border, if any.

So, if you have width 400, padding left 20, right 10, margin 20 (10 on each side), and 4 pixels of border (2 on each side), your whole box will be `400+20+10+20+4=454px`

So, if you were trying to fit that into a space that is only 400 pixels wide, you need to reduce things somewhere; you could, for example, reduce the width by 54 pixels to make the resulting total 400.

---

Note that this does not apply to "Quirks Mode", which uses a slightly different box model, as noted in Sean's answer. This will only apply to IE without a proper doctype; it is generally desireable to avoid quirks mode.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the [box model](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) the browser is using.  The two possibilities are:

- `content-box`: the width of an element *excludes* the padding and border properties.  This is the default model for everything except IE in quirks mode.
- `border-box`: the width of the element *includes* the padding and border.

In [newer browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) you can choose which to use using the `box-sizing` attribute.

Therefore, given the code you provided in the `content-box` model the width of the `div` will be:

```
  400  # from width
+  20  # from padding-left
+  10  # from padding-right
+   4  # from the left and right borders
+  20  # from the left and right margins
-----------------------------------------
Physical width = 454
Content width  = 400
```

While the `border-box` model will set the width of the `div` to:

```
  366  # the declared width is shrunk by the amount of padding and border
+  20  # from padding-left
+  10  # from padding-right
+   4  # from the left and right borders
+  20  # from the left and right margins
-----------------------------------------
Physical width = 420
Content width  = 366
```

See [Quirk's Mode's excellent article on the subject](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) for more information.

Comment: I would note that `border-box` only applies in Quirks mode. Which you sort of did in the content-box area, I guess! hehe